# Modelling probability over window of a time series

Tags: probability, bayesian

I have a binary time series

$
[A, B, B, A, A, A, B, B, A, B, A, B, A]
$

I am trying to answer questions like:
- What is the probability of B occurring if previous day was A?
- What is the probability of B occurring if there were two A in previous 3 days?

In general what is the probability of B occurring if there were $m$ number of A in a window of previous $n$ days.

While I understand that the forum requires the question poster to demonstrate what have they attempted, in this case, I don't even know how to approach the problem.

Comment: Do you mean in the example you give, or in general? If the latter you would need more details to get an answer.

Comment: Not sure but feels like poisson distribution may be worth experimenting with.

Comment: @mdewey The example questions are to communicate better, trying model the general solution. What additional information may be helpful?

Comment: Maybe something like a hidden Markov model could be interesting in this context? Not too familiar with such methods but it came to my mind when reading the question